# Upgrading Mac OS X 10.5.8 Corrupted Lightroom 2.7

Tags: macos, macbook, adobe-lightroom

I use Photoshop CS4 and Lightroom 2.  I recntly upgraded to 10.5.8 and began to have issues with LR.  So, I reinstalled and downgraded my OS.  I'm now running 10.5.2 on my MacBook 2.4G Core Duo with 4G RAM.

Everything works fine now, but the downgrade also resulted in having only Safari 3.0.4 and and older version of iTunes.  I can't upgrade either of those until I upgrade the OS but I'm reluctant to do so because I might have problems again.  Any suggestions?  Install 10.6 instead?  What kind of issues can I expect from that?

Comment: Did you retry installing Lightroom after updating to 10.5.8?

Answer (score 0):

i think it's generally a good idea to run the latest versions of software. here's what i'd do.

1. do a full backup. [superduper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [carbon copy cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) are great at this.
2. do an upgrade to 10.6. no need to do a clean install.
3. run all your os and adobe updates.

if you have any problems then, then post those specific issues.

Comment: There might be compelling reasons to *not* use Snow Leopard.

Comment: agreed, but for the average user, snow leopard works. if tedd is unsure, i think it's still prudent to go up to 10.5.8 and solve the problem there...